# Is there a way to make the channel name the content of the message?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I need to make the channel name the content of the last message. I am aware of the API limits (2 changes in 10 minutes), so I only want it to run every 5 minutes.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
  const prefix = " ";
    
  function myfunction () {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;{
      var var1 = message.content();
      channel.setName(`-counting`+ var1);
    } 
}
      
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
    
client.on('message', message =>{
  setInterval(myfunction,);
});
```

Comment: What is your issue? Error, not working? If it's an error code please add it to your code. And what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: You are creating a setInterval for `myFunction()` each message, which is being repeated each **50 ms**. I'd recommend only executing the `myFunction()` only once since you are literally spamming the Discord's API without a good reason.

Comment: So far. there's no error code.
As I said in the post, I want to change the name of the channel to the latest message but due to API restrictions, I can only limit it to change once per 5 minutes.

Comment: Well you can't do that, it's impossible. Discord specifically made a rate limit to stop people from doing this kinds of things. It can severely slow down Discord's API and even the Discord itself

Comment: You can only change it once per 5 minutes because your code is inefficient and spamming the API. I'm going to write an answer soon and improve your current code.

Comment: @Jakye He is not asking how to do it every 5 minutes, he is asking how to go as he wants (every last message) which is impossible because of Discord's Rate Limit.

Comment: I will restate my question. I want to be able to create something EVERY 5 MINUTES reads the last message and sets that to the channel name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Jakye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10012735/jakye) pointed out in the comments, your current code creates an `setInterval` on every message which is not what you want I presume. I reckon the best course of action would be to save the latest message, define a function that sets the channel name, and create a `setInterval` on the `ready` event. Take a look at the code example below:

```js
const prefix = '<YOUR PREFIX>';
let latestMessage = undefined;

function updateChannelName() {
    // If the latestMessage is undefined, return out of the function
    if (!latestMessage) return;
    latestMessage.channel.setName(`-counting${latestMessage.content}`);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    // Once the client is ready, create the interval.
    // The 5 * 60 * 1000 equals to 5 minutes in milliseconds but it's more readable than writing 300000
    setInterval(updateChannelName, (5 * 60 * 1000));
});

client.on('message', message => {
    // Check for author and prefix
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    // Update the latestMessage to the latest message
    latestMessage = message;
});
```